# Eclipse - Groovy gets/sets appear as errors with Scala IDE installed

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide, groovy-eclipse

I have the following Groovy class:

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
class GitChangeset {
    String hash
    String commitMessage = ""
    String author = ""
    String authorEmail = ""
    String commitLink = ""
    String[] parents = []
    LocalDateTime time
}
```

I have both the Scala and Groovy eclipse plugins (Scala IDE 3.0.3 and Greclipse/Groovy-Eclipse 2.8.0) installed.  I have the following snippet of Java code which *compiles* but does not appear to compile:

[image: Image of java code]

The file does not have a compilation error displayed (yes, build automatically is turned on):

[image: Image of GitService.java that has no errors on it]

If I remove the Scala IDE plugin, this now appears to compile correctly.

Comment: The method setAuthor(String) is undefined for the type GitChangeset
https://i.imgur.com/CTtLcJI.png